# Projection of a complex vector into another

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

A projection of real vectors is given by
$proj_x y = (y^T \cdot x) \frac{x}{x^T x}$

I am not familiar with complex-valued spaces, but could I generalize the projection of complex valued vectors as

$proj_x y = (y^H \cdot x) \frac{x}{x^H x}$, where H is the Hermition operation?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it's done. The $y^H \cdot x$ is an inner product, and this formula works for any inner product space.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Thanks for your answer. The inner product order matters in this case, right?

Comment: Oops you're right order does matter, and the order is the wrong way round here. The Hermitian conjugate should be applied to the $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a slightly longer comment, In order to understand why the order matters, we need to recall that a projection, can be characterized by a projection matrix, i.e. a matrix $P$ such that $P=P^H$ and $P^2=P$. in your case, the projection matrix is $P=\frac{1}{x^H x} x x^H$. It is a projection matrix, and also that its span is the span of $\{ x \}$. Now multiplying $P\cdot y=\frac{x^H y}{x^Hx}x$.

By the way, I have a tendency to consider inner products in the nominator of expression as $1\times 1$ matrices, this typically gives me more intuition about the expression I am working with. If you do this then $y^T x$ cannot be multiplied on the left by $x$, only on the right, therefore the correct expression is $x y^T x$ which indeed feels wrong for a projection.